# Read each Thrift messages as a RAW data

Tags: c++, thrift

As it is known, TCP messages can be split into several packets. I want to read all thrift messages one-by-one as blobs (without parsing it), but I want to be sure where the messages begins and ends.

Thrift offers transport layer (eg. `TBufferedTransport`), where I can read data as bytes, but no information about each message beginning and ending is provided.

On the other hand, thrift offers `StatsProcessor` which parses all the data just to make some statistics and is able to print each messages, but it doesn't provide the way to get the messages as a RAW bytes.

In a short question: How can I read each messages as a RAW data (preferably in C++)?

Comment: How about just using Wireshark or writing a plugin for it ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I need that data in my application's memory.